# Jquery + AJAX + ASP.Net + WebForms

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have some JQuery AJAX POSTing data to my backend C# WebForm.  It POSTs to a static string WebForm method which returns a value, the JQuery uses that value to change an image url in the html.  All is fine and dandy.

However, I would like to expand the functionality of the existing code (though I'm not shut out to rewriting it altogether) to allow me to manipulate the front end ASP controls from the C# backend, which I can not do due to the said static string method acting as my WebForm.

Does anyone have any ideas to help my predicament?

Backend

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ImageLoad(string address)
    {
        //if fail
        return "/Unavailable.bmp";

        //if succeed
        return "myimage.jpg";
        //third option
        else
        return "myotherimage.jpg";
    }
```

JQuery/AJAX

```
function scriptImageLoad() {
   var address = $("#txtAddress").val();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "myPage.aspx/ImageLoad",
           data: "{'address':'" + address.toString() + "'}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "text",
           success: function (output) {
                $('#imgImage').attr('src', output);
           }
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a colleague, I developed a different solution.  A structure holds the output data I desire, it is then transfered into a string array, then returned via the static string web method.  Once returned to the Jquery, the data is pushed to where it needs to go by the different indexes of the array.

Front end

```
function scriptImageLoad() {
   var address = $("#txtAddress").val();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "MyForm.aspx/MyMethod",
         data: "{'address':'" + address.toString() + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "JSON",

         success: function (output) {
            $.each(output, function (index, value) {
               place value in form
               return (index != 0);
            })
            $.each(output, function (index, value) {
               place value in form
               return (index != 1);
            })
            $.each(output, function (index, value) {
               place value in form
               return (index != 2);
            })
            $.each(output, function (index, value) {
               $('#imgImage').attr('src', this);
               return (index != 3);
            })
         }
```

Back end

```
    public struct TestStruct
    {
        public string value1;
        public string value2;
        public string value3;
        public string value4;

        public TestStruct(string value1, string value2, string value3, string value4)
        {
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
            this.value3 = value3;
            this.value4 = value4;
        }
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string[] MyMethod(string address)
    {
        string[] returnarray = new string[4];
        TestStruct struct;
        struct.value1 = "";
        struct.value2 = address;
        struct.value3 = "";
        struct.value4 = "/Unavailable.bmp";

        //if fail, return default values
                returnstring.SetValue(struct.value1, 0);
                returnstring.SetValue(struct.value2, 1);
                returnstring.SetValue(struct.value3, 2);
                returnstring.SetValue(struct.value4, 3);
                return returnstring;

        //if succeed
                struct.values = processed values;
                set the values on returnstring
                return returnstring;
        //else
                struct.values = other processed values;
                set the values on returnstring
                return returnstring;
    }
```

Now the only issues I have is getting the Jquery to properly display the data to the client.

Comment: which I got working by replacing all of my ".this" tags with ".value" tags.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx). This will allow you to call the service with jQuery anywhere in your website.

```
function scriptImageLoad() {
   var address = $("#txtAddress").val();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "MyService.asmx/ImageLoad",
           data: "{'address':'" + address.toString() + "'}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "text",
           success: function (output) {
                $('#imgImage').attr('src', output);
           }
       });
   }
});

[WebService, ScriptService]
public class MyService : WebService
{
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static string ImageLoad(string address)
    {
        //if fail
        return "/Unavailable.bmp";

        //if succeed
        return "myimage.jpg";
        //third option
        else
        return "myotherimage.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: I was advised by a colleague to stay away from WebServices, they don't quite fit my need.

Comment: Why did they advise you to stay away from WebServices?

Comment: The aim/goal of my web application would not benefit from the use of a webservice.  I would still come across the same issues I currently am.

I have however devised a new solution to my problem.  I am currently using a structure to house my outputs and then returning those outputs in a string array.

Answer (score 2):

A postback of some sort is required to process server controls.

Update panels are your only real choice for working with asp.net controls in this scenario.

But I would suggest finding another approach - update panels are evil and will give you warts. the bad kind.

Comment: @joo - not soon enough. but I will never be free - codeplex is one big update panel and I have several projects there. will be a user/victim of update panels for the indefinite future. ;-\